# getting error while working of peopletools

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

Peopletools 8.52 Application portal automatically signout while working on customized and deveopled pages .. other pages works fine but when starts working on customized pages , it stop working takes some time and sign out .. kindly guide to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

First, check your appserver logs to see if an error is occurring. It could be a timeout error if your code is taking too long, or the query is too large, etc. See if you have any error messages, and get back to us after that.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have not given proper roles and permissions to your customized page. Add the proper admin or user roles and permissions while registering the component to the portal.